# Python behaves differently when running file directly vs importing it

Tags: python, scikit-learn

For example, if I do `python module.py` vs `import module`, they behave differently. The module runs some code immediately after being ran or imported.

Specifically, I'm trying to use `LogisticRegressionCV` from sklearn. If I import the module, `LogisticRegressionCV`'s `fit` method freezes if it uses more than 1 job. If I run it directly through `python module.py`, it wouldn't freeze if it uses multiple jobs. Why is this?

Comment: have you looked at the source? https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L1309

Comment: You know the rules. Show us a [mcve].

Comment: If this is a common problem, then the solution should be obvious to Python experts. If not, then it's probably an environment/packages problem, which would be out of the scope of an SO question.